# Send audio data to API via curl

Tags: curl, audio

I need to send the PC's microphone sound continuously to a API via curl. I've come so far as to grab the sound with following command:

```
arecord --buffer-time=1 - | aplay
```

My idea is then to pipe this sound to curl as such:

```
arecord -f cd - | aplay - | curl --digest -u root:pass -d "$(</dev/stdin)" -H "Content-Type: audio/basic" "http://someAPI"
```

But no sound is heard on the receiving end. Is there another way to send the sound generated from arecord and aplay to a API via curl?

Note that sending a file works fine and audio is played on the receiving end with following command:

```
curl --digest -u root:pass -d@g711_basic.au -H "Content-Type: audio/basic" "http://someAPI
```

Best regards